# get Javascript event of php flush

Tags: javascript, php, flush

I have a huge table that PHP gets from a db and displays. Every time php echos a few rows of the table, it flushes the output. So from the client's point of view, the table is basically growing bigger every few seconds.

Is it possible to get a JavaScript event every time new data comes in so I can do some processing on the table?

Comment: How big is the table?  How many columns, how many rows?

Comment: like 200 rows, but each row might contain a lot of data, so lets say maybe every 5 seconds it dumps 5 rows

Comment: How much data?  2 MB per row, 10, 100, 200.  What is the data, text, json, xml.  Why are you dumping it all at once to the client?

Comment: I just want to know if there are javascript events that are tied to php flushes. If not then I want to know if there are ways to detect php flushes. I'm not in a good position to change how it's done.

Comment: There aren't any javascript events to catch php flushes. You should also lazy load the data rather than getting it all immediately.

Comment: You can't detect php fluses from javascript.

Comment: That's true, it''s an old application with some seriously messy code. I guess I'll try to spend the time to make it load via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using something like [Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) which can display Millions of records quickly and efficiently.  You should not be trying to do this with PHP buffers.

I personally use it with a dataset of 100,000 rows and it is lightning fast.

Comment: just a note, slickgrid is no longer maintained - so probably best to go with something else

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree,  Slickgrid is a very good piece of software just because its not under active maintenance by its origional author does not make it worse.

Comment: It's a very good piece of kit, yes. No guarantee it will always work with the latest browser though.

Comment: can you provide an example of how to use slickgrid in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a JavaScript function call with each flush.

```
<tr>
 Data ....
</tr>
<script type="text/JavaScript ">
foo();
</script>
```

The function foo will be called after each flush.

Or

Use ajax to load further rows. So, you can trigger JavaScript function on completion of ajax calls.